# MacOS Mountain Lion Users command dscl

Tags: mysql, macos

I am running dscl . -list /Users in the Terminal. I see some users have an _ before the name e.g. _mysql

This "seems" to prevent me setting up a mysql user. Whe I try to set up a mysql user either as root or any other user account I have I get a message that the mysql user already exists. I do not have a Standard or Admin user called "mysql" when I run the dscl command other than the _mysql user.

What does the _ before mysql mean please?

Answer (score 1):

Note the RecordName entry for that account:

```
$ dscl . -read /Users/_mysql
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA0000004A
NFSHomeDirectory: /var/empty
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 74
RealName:
 MySQL Server
RecordName: _mysql mysql
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
UniqueID: 74
UserShell: /usr/bin/false
```

This account's primary name is _mysql, but it has mysql as an alias.

Solution: don't create a mysql account, use the one that's already there.